# MySQL lost connection with system error: 10060

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, localhost, mysql-workbench

I am studying react and node js, to build a full stack login authentication page.
Which I found tutorial from this github : "https://github.com/bezkoder/node-js-jwt-auth".

I found this tutorial extremely confusing due to mysql connection errors, the only edit I made is changing the running port from 8080 to 3306, which is a fast fix for having another port running on 8080.

[When I run "node server.js" this error pops up few seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9uUr.png)

also, in order to view mysql databases, I am running MySQL Workbench localhost:3306, but the server is stopped, refresh wouldn't work, nor restarting the mysql through services.

The Message shows: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'waiting for initial communication packet'. system error 10060.

Please help, I have no idea what I am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't learn how node.js or react work, so start with much simpler tutorials

port 8080 is the port when you type it in the browser localhost:8080 a webpage appears.

So **don't** change it, as long as you don't have another page running.

You start by editng

```
node-js-jwt-auth/app/config/db.config.js
```

There you find

```
module.exports = {
  HOST: "localhost",
  USER: "root",
  PASSWORD: "123456",
  DB: "testdb",
  dialect: "mysql",
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  }
};
```

Here you enter the same data as you enter in workbench.

Of course the mysql server has to be installed and running.

Comment: I only learned how react work, and how mysql works but not nodejs, I changed the port since I was using the port with MAMP. You are correct on starting with simpler tutorials, this is the most obvious yet most effective! Now everything works, Thanks much!